# Redirect old subdomain to new subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I am trying to do the following redirects of an old subdomain to a new subdomain, respectively:

```
sub.mydomain.com/d/(all_files),
sub.mydomain.com/d2/(all_files)
```

redirect to

```
sub2.mydomain.com/d/(all_files),
sub2.mydomain.com/d2/(all_files)
```

There are other folders/files in the original "sub" that will not be redirected.  Only the files in the "d" and the "d2" folders need redirecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RewriteCond` to test for the `HTTP_HOST`:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If it matches sub. the old subdomain,,,
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.
# Redirect URLs starting with d/ or d2/ into sub2.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^(d2?)/(.*)$ http://sub2.mydomain.com/$1/$2 [L,R=301]
```

The expression `^(d2?)` is:

- `^` start of the string
- `d` followed by an optional `2` (`?` means previous expression is optional)
- `()` whole thing is captured for reuse in `$1`

Comment: Will the new 'sub2.mydomain.com' show in the URL bar for the rewritten urls from /d and /d2??

Comment: I just want to be clear.  With the above rule, I will get the following:

requests for:
sub.mydomain.com/d/file_or_folder
will return:
sub2.mydomain.com/d/file_or_folder

and

requests for:
sub.mydomain.com/d2/file_or_folder
will return:
sub2.mydomain.com/d2/file_or_folder

Comment: @CarrlosBoyd Yes, the R=301 redirect will fully redirect the browser, and it will show the new subdomain in the URL bar.

Comment: I am having to revisit this with slight adjustment. I need to move everything in the following subdomain: http://sub.domain.com to http://newdomain.com so that http:sub.domain.com/folder1/file2 redirects to http://newdomain.com/folder1/file2. Can you help?

Comment: Here is what I did and it seems to be working:  
`RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.  
RewriteRule http://www.newdomain.com/$1/$2 [L,R=301]`